Dualising the Morse complex
I keep getting stuck on the details of the construction of the Morse co-chain complex. Here, $f$ is a Morse function for a compact manifold $M$ of dimension $m$. The Morse complex (with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_2$) is given by
$$... \overset{\partial_{k+1}}{\longrightarrow} C_k(f) \overset{\partial_k}{\longrightarrow} C_{k-1}(f) \overset{\partial_{k-1}}{\longrightarrow} ...$$
I want to find a nice way to describe its dualisation
$$... \overset{\partial^\ast_{k-1}}{\longrightarrow} C^\ast_{k-1}(f) \overset{\partial^\ast_k}{\longrightarrow} C^\ast_k(f) \overset{\partial^\ast_{k+1}}{\longrightarrow} ...$$
to compute the cohomology of $M$.
The idea: Since all of the $C_k(f)$ are finite dimensional $\mathbb{F}_2$-spaces, they are isomorphic to their duals. This means we can define the maps $\partial^\ast_k$ on them. This is where I get stuck. I've seen people define differentials (that are essentially the same as the boundary maps $\partial_k$):
$$d_{k-1} : C_{k-1}(f) \longrightarrow C_k(f) : d_k(p) := \sum_{q \in C_k(f)}\begin{pmatrix} \text{number of gradient lines} \\\text{adjoining $p$ and $q$ mod 2}\end{pmatrix} \cdot q.$$
Then they define
$$H^k(M) :=\text{ker}\,d_k/\text{im}\,d_{k-1}.$$
The problem: I can't convince myself that this $d_{k-1}$ (as defined above) is the dual of $\partial_k$. Could anyone help to clear this up? Thank you.

By identifying $C_k \cong C_k^*$, one induces a 'duality product' on $C_k$: given two critical points $p, q \in C_{\bullet}$, one has $(p,q) = 1$ if $p=q$ and $0$ otherwise.
Considering $p \in C_k$ and $q \in C_{k-1}$, then
$$(p, d_{k-1}q) = (\partial_k p, q) = \mbox{number of gradient lines (mod $2$) connecting $p$ and $q$}.$$
From these two paragraphs, one deduces that $d_{k-1}q$ is the sum of those $p \in C_k$ having an odd number of gradient lines connecting to $q$.

Concise and very clear, thank you!
